# Convert List to Json

Tags: json, circe

How do I create a Json (Circe) looking like this:

```
{
 "items": [{
   "field1": "somevalue",
   "field2": "somevalue2"
  },
  {
   "field1": "abc",
   "field2": "123abc"
  }]
}
```

`val result = Json.fromFields(List("items" -> ???))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so using Circe's built in list typeclasses for encoding JSON. This code will work:

```scala
import io.circe.{Encoder, Json}
import io.circe.syntax._

case class Field(field1: String, field2: String)

object Field {
  implicit val encodeFoo: Encoder[Field] = new Encoder[Field] {
    final def apply(a: Field): Json = Json.obj(
      ("field1", Json.fromString(a.field1)),
      ("field2", Json.fromString(a.field2))
    )
  }
}

class Encoding(items: List[Field]) {
  def getJson: Json = {
    Json.obj(
      (
        "items", 
        items.asJson
      )
    )
  }
}
```

If we instantiate an "Encoding" class and call getJson it will give you back the desired JSON. It works because with circe all you need to do to encode a list is provide an encoder for whatever is inside the list. Thus, if we provide an encoder for Field it will encode it inside a list when we call asJson on it.

If we run this:

```scala
val items = new Encoding(List(Field("jf", "fj"), Field("jfl", "fjl")))

println(items.getJson)
```

we get:

```
{
  "items" : [
    {
      "field1" : "jf",
      "field2" : "fj"
    },
    {
      "field1" : "jfl",
      "field2" : "fjl"
    }
  ]
}
```